# Postfix on a Zimbra Collaborative Suite server - error in mail.log

Tags: zimbra

Fist time posting on this site, so please forgive if I'm not following the standard procedure... ;-)

I have a ZCS (Zimbra Collaborative Suite) server that runs on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS  (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-210-generic x86_64)

I ran recently a command to get updates done:
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
and saw nothing that could warn me of any issue.

Now I've got a few errors in mail.log:

```
> May 11 09:09:02 zimbra8 postfix/qmgr[21567]: 37C531831D3:
> from=<0w1re9ryrwao94oulz8cdewb5ckkftoq-b@bounce.bronto.com>,
> size=112338, nrcpt=1 (queue active) May 11 09:09:02 zimbra8
> postfix/qmgr[21567]: warning: **connect to transport
> private/smtp-amavis: Connection refused** May 11 09:09:02 zimbra8
> postfix/qmgr[21567]: C8D02183118:
> from=<20210510182030deef81a1b8d04d17b18b4b8ab820p0na@bounces.amazon.ca>,
> size=39784, nrcpt=1 (queue active) May 11 09:09:02 zimbra8
> postfix/qmgr[21567]: 519DD183139:
> from=<no_reply_support@trust-provider.com>, size=6559, nrcpt=1 (queue
> active) May 11 09:09:02 zimbra8 postfix/qmgr[21567]: 57718183187:
> from=<bounce-52_HTML-6880901-615832-7210119-4003@bounce.communications.bestbuypromotions.ca>,
> size=85852, nrcpt=1 (queue active) May 11 09:09:03 zimbra8
> postfix/error[32485]: C8D02183118: to=<bmunger@ingenieur.org>,
> relay=none, delay=67711, delays=67711/0.02/0/0.54, dsn=4.3.0,
> **status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)** May 11 09:09:03 zimbra8
> postfix/error[32489]: 57718183187: to=<vincent@ingenieur.org>,
> relay=none, delay=13091, delays=13090/0.02/0/0.54, dsn=4.3.0,
> status=deferred (mail transport unavailable) May 11 09:09:03 zimbra8
> postfix/error[32484]: 37C531831D3: to=<vero@ingenieur.org>,
> relay=none, delay=492, delays=492/0.01/0/0.55, dsn=4.3.0,
> status=deferred (mail transport unavailable) May 11 09:09:03 zimbra8
> postfix/error[32487]: 519DD183139: to=<admin@ingenieur.org>,
> orig_to=<admin@emails.ingenieur.org>, relay=none, delay=21158,
> delays=21158/0.02/0/0.54, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport
> unavailable)
```

I'm searching and not finding the exact issue.

I can post the config files in a subsequent reply.

Thanks!
Bernard

Comment: I tried disabling Amavis, but I still get the Postfix error that mail transport unavailable.

Comment: Seems that your Postfix config may have changed during the upgrade. Do you have a backup?